# Cookies not loading in UIWebView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, xamarin, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that authenticates a user. After the user is authenticated I save and delete the cookies like so :-

```
 public static void SaveCookies()
    {
        NSHttpCookieStorage cookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
        foreach (var nscookie in cookieStorage.Cookies)
        {
            cookieStorage.SetCookie(nscookie);
        }


    }
    public static void DeleteCookies()
    {
        NSHttpCookieStorage cookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
        foreach (var nscookie in cookieStorage.Cookies)
        {
            cookieStorage.DeleteCookie(nscookie);
        }


    }
```

I have this line in my AppDelegate

```
public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. 
            // If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
           NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
        }
```

I call SaveCookies like so :

```
var authResponse = REsponse after authentication
                 if (authResponse != null)
                 {
                    //SAve cookies here
                     AppDelegate.SaveCookies();
                    ...
                 }
```

But Iam not sure how to load and pass the Cookies to the webview on the next app launch so that the user is not shown the login page again. Right now the Login page is shown on every app launch. I want to enable a One time login. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `iOS 9`, apple introduced new controller called, `SafariViewController`. This controller takes care of all cookies and cache stuff for you. Following is the way to use this.

```
    SFSafariViewController * cntrl = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yahoomail.com"] entersReaderIfAvailable:YES];
cntrl.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:cntrl animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

In place of http://yahoomail.com above pass your web url.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. But iam not using iOS 9. Im using iOS 8.3

Comment: Ok, not sure about that :)